# CheckBox List not saving YII

Tags: php, jquery, yii, checkboxlist

I have two checkbox list with same model column name,but while saving only last checkbox list values are saving in database. below is code for checkbox list:-

```
<?php $list = CHtml::listData(Model::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'id>=17 && id<=26', 'order' => 'name ASC')),'id','name'); } ?>
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'list',$list,array('multiple'=>true,'disabled'=>false)); ?>
<?php $list = CHtml::listData(Model::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'id>=27 && id<=39', 'order' => 'name ASC')),'id','name'); } ?>
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'list',$list,array('multiple'=>true,'disabled'=>false)); ?>
```

How to save Both checkboxlist values in database.

Comment: I'm using yii2 but, if you have same name checkboxes only the last will be sended because overwrite the first values. You should change the 'list'.

Comment: @MrRP but in model the column name is list only and both checkbox list value should be saved in same table.

Comment: So you should use the static [checkBoxList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail). It doesn't depends on model.

Comment: @MrRP but i want to get checkbox list from database i cant define static one. By Any other way we cant do that (ie. either jquery, javascript etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array_merge function to merge both values of array then save the merge value in database.